# Is there a way to further split a grouped ggplot bar chart by another grouping variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

A dput() of data I wish to use this on is included below.

I am trying to plot a bar chart (stacked or not) which visualises the count of people with and without a binary characteristic (in this case, LGE presence). I then want to show two grouped pairs of bars next to each other, namely the first and last MRI measurement. I then want those measurements split by the treatment/control grouping variable subject_group.

So far, I used `ggplot(data_lge_long, aes(variable)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = value))` and got part of the way, but I can't figure out how to split the stacked bars by treatment group.

Result so far:
[image: Plot]

Data:

```
dput(data_lge_long)
structure(list(subject_group = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("eplerenone", "no treatment"), class = "factor"), 
    variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("first_mri_lge_yn", 
    "last_mri_lge_yn"), class = "factor"), value = c("no LGE", 
    "no LGE", "no LGE", "LGE present", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", 
    "no LGE", "no LGE", "LGE present", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", 
    "LGE present", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "LGE present", 
    "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", 
    "LGE present", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", 
    "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", 
    "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", 
    "no LGE", "LGE present", "LGE present", "LGE present", "no LGE", 
    "no LGE", "LGE present", "no LGE", "no LGE", "LGE present", 
    "no LGE", "no LGE", "LGE present", "no LGE", "LGE present", 
    "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "LGE present", 
    "LGE present", "no LGE", "LGE present", "LGE present", "LGE present", 
    "LGE present", "no LGE", "LGE present", "no LGE", "no LGE", 
    "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "LGE present", 
    "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "LGE present", 
    "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "LGE present", "no LGE", "no LGE", 
    "no LGE", "no LGE", "LGE present", "no LGE", "LGE present", 
    "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", 
    "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", 
    "no LGE", "no LGE", "LGE present", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", 
    "LGE present", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "LGE present", 
    "LGE present", "LGE present", "LGE present", "no LGE", "no LGE", 
    "LGE present", "no LGE", "LGE present", "LGE present", "no LGE", 
    "no LGE", "LGE present", "LGE present", "LGE present", "no LGE", 
    "LGE present", "no LGE", "no LGE", "no LGE", "LGE present", 
    "LGE present", "no LGE", "LGE present", "LGE present", "LGE present", 
    "no LGE", "LGE present", "LGE present", "no LGE", "LGE present", 
    "no LGE", "LGE present")), row.names = c(NA, -152L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You seem to have omitted the start of your `dput` output and your current image is not being displayed.  As a result, I'm not entirely sure what you want.  But I suspect `interaction()` may be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah.  The problem with `dput` and the graph was due to a formatting problem in your post.  Here are a few options that may give you close to what you want.

```
ggplot(d, aes(variable)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = interaction(value, subject_group)))
```

[image]

and

```
ggplot(d, aes(variable)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = value), position="dodge") + 
  facet_wrap(~subject_group)
```

[image]

and

```
ggplot(d, aes(variable)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = interaction(value, subject_group)), position="dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: You already perfectly answered my question, but I edited the dput. Facet_grid was the solution. I actually remembered I used this before, but your reply came before I made the connection. Thank you, question resolved.

Comment: Facet_wrap, sorry.